# Smart way to execute function in test n times and check each result in jasmine anynchronous code

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, promise, rxjs

I have a spec file:

```
export class StaticClass() {
  public static doSomething(): Promise<any> {
    public static id = randomString(8); //makes a random from letters
   }
}

it('should execute n times', done => {

for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   StaticClass.doSomething(parameter).then((done) => {
     let id = StaticClass.id;
     console.log(id);
     expect(id).toBeSomething(); //not important here
     done();
   });
}

afterEach(()=> console.log('after each'));


});
```

Problem is that I get id which is always the same and the test passes immediately.

Output is:

```
0
1 
2
.. 
19
edbcjiia
edbcjiia
edbcjiia
..
19 times the same string
afterEach
```

I want to check something with the string generated by Static Helper class. Maybye use RxJs inteval somehow ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's even valid Typescript that you have in the StaticClass. Please provide an accurate example. :)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html is useful if you want to coble up some quick code online.

Comment: Yeah it's about idea here.

Comment: a good example matters a lot in getting a good response. It's also recommended in the how to ask a good question guide. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your "idea" doesn't really make sense here. It's like you expect `after each` to be printed after each iteration in the for loop. What do you *really* want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `done` in every `then` of the function (which executes multiple times). It doesn't make a lot of sense if you want to wait for all the actions. You're also overriding `done` with the `then` parameter which makes no sense;

Instead, you should wait for all the requests:

```
it('should execute n times', done => {

var p = Promise.resolve(); // create chain
for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
   p  = p.then(() => { // only execute after the last one is done.
     return StaticClass.doSomething(parameter).then(() => {
       expect(StaticClass.id).toBeSomething(); //not important here
     });
  }); // then returns a new promise and waits for the internal promise
}

afterEach(()=> console.log('after each'));
```